# How to open the calendar on page near the input element by using OwlDatepicker?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular8, angular-fullstack

I am using owlDateTimepicker for implementing the purpose of datetime calendar as its not available in Material. 
I am facing a strange issue. I am getting the datetime calendar but when we click on input box it opens but with backdrop with background transparent. When that datetime picker is opened all other elements unloads from HTML page. Please can someone help. I want to open that datetime picker over there itself.

[image: Please see the img for more info. There is form behind that white background which needs to be seen even if the datetime picker opens.]

Note - I dont want to cover the whole form by that backdrop after clicking on the calendar.

[image: In short I want to open the calendar by this way beside the input element but by using OWLDATETIMEPICKER]

Comment: You can use form controls.

Comment: Can you give me an example? @Vijay

Comment: Please check the solution below. Thumbs up if it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could use form controls instead. And find the date time using Reactive Forms. Below is snippet which might be helpful to you.

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label> Date<span class="mandatory warning-red">*</span></label>
          <input type="date"
                 class="form-control"
                 formControlName="control_name"
                 value="{{currentRow.property_Name| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" />
</div>
```